# Moving specific files to another folder using groovy

Tags: java, file, groovy

I'm trying to move files with specific names to a different folder. The code moves only file at a time I want to move all the files at once.

```
def p1= folderpath1
def p2= folderpath2
def d= new File(p2)
def filesubstr= "hello"
def filepattern= ~/${filesubstr}/
def findfile=
{
if(filepattern.matcher(it.name).find()) {
it.renameTo(p2)
}
d.eachFileRecurse(findfile)
```

And for every time I have to specify a new filename for moving a file. I don't understand why this is happeninng.

```
def p2= 'E:\\xyz\\newfile1'
```

after one file moves I have to again specify new file name

```
def p2= 'E:\\xyz\\newfile2'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be the `AntBuilder` included in groovy distributions.

The following code:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

ant.move(todir: 'targetfolder', overwrite: true, force: true, flatten: false) {
  fileset(dir: 'sourcefolder', includes: '**/foo*')
  regexpmapper(from: '(.*)foo(.*)', to: '\\1bar\\2', handledirsep: true)
}
```

and the following directory structures for `sourcefolder` and `targetfolder`:

```
─➤ tree sourcefolder 
sourcefolder
├── baz.txt
├── foo1.txt
├── foo.txt
├── subdirA
│   └── foo2.txt
└── subdirB
    └── foo3.txt

2 directories, 5 files

─➤ tree targetfolder 
targetfolder

0 directories, 0 files

─➤
```

result in the following when executing the code:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy 
     [move] Moving 4 files to targetfolder

─➤ tree sourcefolder 
sourcefolder
├── baz.txt
├── subdirA
└── subdirB

2 directories, 1 file

─➤ tree targetfolder 
targetfolder
├── bar1.txt
├── bar.txt
├── subdirA
│   └── bar2.txt
└── subdirB
    └── bar3.txt

2 directories, 4 files

─➤
```

In other words, only the matching files are moved and the moved files are renamed using a regex pattern specified in the `from` and `to` attributes of the `regexmapper`.